# ListView in fragment repeate himself in Android?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I try to make an example about `Fragment` in android and I did it but I have something mistake .
When I put a Custom `ListView` to display a list of items in tab from fragment tabs I see it displayed very normal but when I move to another tab and back to the last tab (list of links)
I see it be list*2 I mean double list ex:(if I have 2 item when I back I see 4 items !!) And this is my code...

MainActivity Class

```
 import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.examples.borsacapital.R;
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener{

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private FragmentAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Main", "Stocks", "Links"  };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.Favorites :
            Intent i = new Intent(this,Favorites.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.CopyRights :
            Intent ii = new Intent(this,CopyRights.class);
            startActivity(ii);
            break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Links Class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.examples.borsacapital.R;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Links extends Fragment {
    ListView listView;
    List<LinksDetails> model = new ArrayList<LinksDetails>();
    ArrayAdapter<LinksDetails> adapter1 = null;


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_links,container ,false);
        listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);

        int y = listView.getCount();
        if (y == 0) {

        final String[] values  = new String[] { "BorsaCapital", "Email", "Facebook",
                    "Twitter", "Google+", "Skype", "LinkedIn", "Yahoo",
                    "Amazon", "Blogyy", "SoundCloud", "Our Cloud", "Flaker" };

            for (int x = 0; x < values.length; x++) {
                LinksDetails L = new LinksDetails();
                L.setLID(x);
                L.setLName(values[x]);
                L.setLImage("F");

                adapter1 = new LinksRowActivity(getActivity(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, model);

                adapter1.add(L);

            }

            listView.setAdapter(adapter1);

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(Item_Click);
            return v;
        }

        return null;
    }

    private OnItemClickListener Item_Click = new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,final View view, int position,
                long id) {

            // ListView Clicked item index
            int itemPosition = position;

            // ListView Clicked item value
            String itemValue = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            if (itemPosition == 0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.borsacapital.com/"));
                startActivity(i);
            } else {

                // Show Alert
                Toast.makeText(
                        getActivity(),
                        "Position :" + itemPosition + "  ListItem : "
                                + itemValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }

    };

    class LinksRowActivity extends ArrayAdapter<LinksDetails> {

        public LinksRowActivity(Context context, int resource,
                List<LinksDetails> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
        }

        // problem here =======================
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LinksHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(getArguments());
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_links, parent,
                        false);
                holder = new LinksHolder(convertView);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (LinksHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.populateForm(model.get(position));
            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

LinksHolder Class

```
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LinksHolder {

    private TextView LinkName = null ;
    private ImageView Icon = null;

    LinksHolder(View row){
        this.LinkName =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        this.Icon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.iconImageView);
    }

    public void populateForm(LinksDetails LD){
        LinkName.setText(LD.getLName());
        switch(LD.getLID()){
        case 0:
            Icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            break;
        case 1:
            Icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.email);
            break;
        case 2:
            Icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.facebook);
            break;
        case 3:
            Icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.twitter);
            break;
        case 4:
            Icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.google);
            break;
        case 5:
            Icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.skype);
            break;
        case 6:
            Icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.linkedin);
            break;
        case 7:
            Icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.yahooo);
            break;
        case 8:
            Icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.amazon);
            break;
        case 9:
            Icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.blogger);
            break;
        case 10:
            Icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.soundcloud);
            break;
        case 11:
            Icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.cloud);
            break;
        case 12:
            Icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.flickr);
            break;
        }
    }
```

I think the problem in `getView()` Method in links Class when I open this tab this method is run and position parameter = 13 !!

Comment: You only have 13 items on your Adapter and you are trying to access the item with index 13, that doesn't exist.

Comment: no no no i don't mean this , i mean when open this list i found 13 item and when i leave this list and go back i found 26 item (13x2) !!

Comment: Put a breakpoint in this line: 

`adapter1.add(L);`

See if that line is being executed twice the times that it is expected.

Comment: @joao2fast4u yes this line is being executed twice the times. what i do now ?

Comment: Try to remove this verification:

 `int y = listView.getCount();
        if (y == 0) {...}`

and check if the issue is gone.